# CryptoJS suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I've been using CryptoJS in a web view on `iOS` for a while now without issue, however today I am starting to get the error `Can't find variable: CryptoJS`

The links to `http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js` and `http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js` seem to have gone.

Does anyone know of an alternative location for this?

Comment: Depending on a crypto library without HTTPS and fixed/trusted version seems… Well. *Interesting*. However, you can [still download the code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/downloads) and host it yourself. Keep in mind that CryptoJS isn't maintained anymore.

Comment: And neither is Google Code...

Comment: Ok, hosting it myself seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: At the time I guess it seemed the sane thing to do, just like it's become common practice to use `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`