# Crypto-js lib is not available anymore

Tags: cryptojs

I have used following library for many years and now it is not available.
http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js

Can someone help to find alternative?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186896/cryptojs-suddenly-stopped-working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the library sources you need from here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/downloads

Then put them on your own server ... then replace
http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js
by
/directory_where_you_put_the_download/rollups/md5.js

It works for me.

Comment: the code.google.com link is fine, that links to a zip with the files. The other links you mention are broken.  e.g. `wget http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js` gives a 404, also you need to load core.js first. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

It is still hosted on cdnjs, I found the working URLs for it  See my answer [How to generate an MD5 file hash in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733374/how-to-generate-an-md5-file-hash-in-javascript/57220077#57220077)

the URLs to the individual js files such as md5.js have changed(and besides that , you need to load core.js first)

try `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/core.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/md5.js"></script>` and see https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js for URLs

and you can use code such as e.g.

```
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("Message");
console.log(hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm always visiting https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js when I need anything like this. Free and open source CDN. You can find many versions there.